# SQL Server CE 4.0 Installation problems

Tags: installation, sql-server-ce

I have downloaded the latest version of SQLServer CE 4.0 and am trying to install it. After downloading and saving it to my local machine I double-click on the EXE. Then it presents me with the "Do You Want to Run This File" dialog box to which I, of course, answer "yes".

That's it ... nothing else. I open up Task Manager to see if it is busy and I locate the "Image Name" - SSCERRuntime_x64ENU.exe*32 - and it's not doing anything. It is occupying a little memory (between 800K - 1400K) and is not using the CPU at all ... at all?

I have no idea why this would  be happening and have run out of ideas. I ultimately kill the process and be on my way but I NEED SQL-CE 4.0 installed.

I am willing to try anything (within reason of course ;))

Running Windows 7 Enterprise x64.

Thanks,
G

Comment: Try to install it using Web Platform Installer http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx and let us know

Comment: Thank you for your response! I had actually tried that first. After several attempts with the WPI, which got  hung every time, I determined it was hanging on the SQL CE installation, so I downloaded the SQL CE installation and attempted to install it directly thinking that that may work me around the WPI problem. Apparently the  problem was the SQL CE install and not WPI.